# Poincaré dual of the generators of $H^d(S^5/\mathbb{Z}_4,\mathbb{Z}_4)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, homology-cohomology, geometric-topology, quotient-spaces

We know [$H^d(S^5/\mathbb{Z}_4,\mathbb{Z}_4)=\mathbb{Z}_4$](https://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Cohomology_of_real_projective_space#Coefficients_in_a_module_over_a_2-divisible_ring). So there are two classes of $\mathbb{Z}_4$ generators, trivial and nontrivial, for $d=0,1,2,3,4,5$.

Wha are the Poincaré dual $(5-d)$-dimensional manifolds of the generators PD($a^d$) of $a^d\in H^d(S^5/\mathbb{Z}_4,\mathbb{Z}_4)$, for $d=0,1,2,3,4,5$?

\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
\text{PD}(a^d)& a^d =0 \in H^d(S^5/\mathbb{Z}_4,\mathbb{Z}_4) &a^d \neq 0 \in H^d(S^5/\mathbb{Z}_4,\mathbb{Z}_4)=\mathbb{Z}_4\\ \hline
d=0  &S^5?& S^5/\mathbb{Z}_4?\\ 
\hline
d=1 &S^4? &?\\ 
\hline
d=2  &S^3?&?\\ 
\hline
d=3  &S^2?&?\\ 
\hline
d=4  &S^1?&?\\ 
\hline
d=5  & \text{a point}?& \text{a point}?\\
\hline
\end{array}

- See also [a useful Ref here: Spin structures and killing spinors on lens spaces, A.Franc](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0393044087900155).